# Как сделать, чтобы линии были кривые и огибали узлы графа в networkx?

Tags: python, графы, networkx

[image: з]

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_edges_from([
  ('t1', 'c1'),
  ('t1', 'c2'),
  ('c1', 'c2'),
  ('c2', 'c1'),
  ('p2', 'c1'),
  ('c2', 'p2')
])

attrs = {'c1':{'key':100},
         'c2':{'key':50},
         't1':{'key':15},
         'p2':{'key':30}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs)

node_sizes = [a['key']*30 for n, a in G.nodes(data=True)]

# drawing ...
pos = {key: [i*3, 0] for key, i in zip(attrs, range(len(attrs)))}
print(pos)
nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True,
        cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'),
        node_size=node_sizes,
        arrows=True, arrowsize=40)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Извините, я не понял вопрос?

Comment: Такой пример подходит?

Comment: К сожалению, нужно узлы графа расположить именно в одну линию

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте начать с [этого варианта](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/networkx-discuss/FwYk0ixLDuY):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch, Circle
import numpy as np

def draw_network(G,pos,ax,sg=None):
    for n in G:
        c=Circle(pos[n],radius=0.02,alpha=0.5)
        ax.add_patch(c)
        G.node[n]['patch']=c
        x,y=pos[n]
    seen={}
    for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True):
        n1=G.node[u]['patch']
        n2=G.node[v]['patch']
        rad=0.1
        if (u,v) in seen:
            rad=seen.get((u,v))
            rad=(rad+np.sign(rad)*0.1)*-1
        alpha=0.5
        color='k'
        e = FancyArrowPatch(n1.center,n2.center,patchA=n1,patchB=n2,
                            arrowstyle='-|>',
                            connectionstyle='arc3,rad=%s'%rad,
                            mutation_scale=10.0,
                            lw=2,
                            alpha=alpha,
                            color=color)
        seen[(u,v)]=rad
        ax.add_patch(e)
    return e

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_edges_from([
  ('t1', 'c1'),
  ('t1', 'c2'),
  ('c1', 'c2'),
  ('c2', 'c1'),
  ('p2', 'c1'),
  ('c2', 'p2')
])

attrs = {'c1':{'key':100},
         'c2':{'key':50},
         't1':{'key':15},
         'p2':{'key':30}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs)
node_sizes = [a['key']*30 for n, a in G.nodes(data=True)]

# drawing ...
pos = {key: [i*3, 0] for key, i in zip(attrs, range(len(attrs)))}

ax=plt.gca()
draw_network(G,pos,ax)
ax.autoscale()
plt.axis('equal')
plt.axis('off')

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, with_labels=True,
                        cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'),
                        node_size=node_sizes)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)

plt.savefig("d:/temp/graph.pdf")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как убрать изначальные ребра?

Comment: @Vadym, используйте `nx.draw_networkx_nodes()` и `nx.draw_networkx_labels()` вместо `nx.draw()`