# Отображение графа с перпендикулярными ребрами Networkx

Tags: python, графы, networkx

Накидал код для генерации случайного графа и отображения оного

```
import random
import networkx
import math
from networkx.generators.random_graphs import gnp_random_graph
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=gnp_random_graph(5, 0.6, seed=None, directed=False)

for (u,v,w) in G.edges(data=True):
    w['weight'] = random.randint(3,5)

e = [(u, v) for (u, v, d) in G.edges(data=True)]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G,weight='weight',scale=20)  # positions for all nodes

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=700)

# edges
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edgelist=e,
                       width=4)

# labels
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=20, font_family='sans-serif')

plt.show()
```

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли отобразить граф так, чтобы все ребра были либо перпендикулярны, либо лежали на одной прямой? С возможным наслоением.

К примеру так:
[image: пример]

Comment: можете прикрепить скетч/рисунок? я не понимаю как это - "чтобы все ребра были перпендикулярны". Если же расположить все узлы на одной прямой, то ребра будут сливаться...

Comment: Далеко не каждый случайный граф можно так отобразить

Comment: Для произвольного графа в принципе нельзя быть уверенным, что возможно построение на плоскости, для которого длинны рёбер были бы пропорциональны весам. Аналогично и с перпендикулярностью - если только не разрешить рёбрам накладываться друг на друга, то вообще нельзя будет изобразить вершины, в которых сходятся больше четырёх рёбер.

Comment: А если без пропорциональности и с наложением рёбер? (исправил вопрос)

Comment: [Так вам подойдет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909700)

Answer (score 1):

За это отвечает параметр layout, который у вас в коде представлен переменной pos. Этот параметр это словарь, в котором ключи это названия вершин, а значения это списки с двумя значениями, координатами x и y.
Реализовать постановку как на вашем примере можно так:

```
pos = {'A': [0, 2],
       'B': [0, 1],
       'C': [2, 1],
       'D': [1, 2],
       'E': [0, 0],
       'F': [1, 1],
       'G': [2, 0]}
```